# How to use paging for retrieving Google docs?

Tags: java, google-docs, google-docs-api

I wand to receive google docs info with paging using Java Client Library.
My code:

```
private static final String URL_STRING = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/";

public List<DocumentListEntry> getAllDocs() throws Exception {
    URL feedUri = new URL(URL_STRING);
    DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(feedUri);
    query.setMaxResults(2);
    query.setStartIndex(1);
    DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(query, DocumentListFeed.class);
    return feed.getEntries();
}
```

And processing entries:

```
List<DocumentListEntry> docList = gDocumentsRetriever.getAllDocs();
for (DocumentListEntry entry : docList) {
    processEntry(oAuthToken, gDocumentsRetriever, entry);
}
```

I get two entries.But if I change

```
query.setStartIndex(1);
```

to

```
query.setStartIndex(3);
```

i get same two entries.

Comment: Can you post the entire code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how this issue can be realized:
http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html#pagingThroughResults

For other services it realizes in the same way.