# google documents api pagination

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

I am using google documents API. I need to implement pagination.

I used like below.

First page:

```
qry.setMaxResults(10);
qry.setStartIndex(1);
```

Second page:

```
qry.setMaxResults(10);
qry.setStartIndex(11);
```

I am getting same 10 results for second page also.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335784/how-to-use-paging-for-retrieving-google-docs) question has [this](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_java.html#pagingThroughResults) as answer link.

I am unable to find any answer in this link. 
Can any one help me?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Documents List API uses "next" tokens for pagination and not the start index:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#getting_all_pages_of_documents_and_files

To retrieve all pages of documents, you start from the beginning and then follow the link with `rel=next` to get more pages.

The max results parameter is used to limit the number of elements in each page.

**Remember you can (and should) also use the newer Drive API to perform the same task:**

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Can you please provide some sample java code to perform this?

Comment: The Drive API documentation includes Java samples for each operation, another reason to start using it